# Connect to Azure Data Explorer Cluster via Visual studio

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm trying to connect to a kusto cluster I created in azure from Visual Studio 2019, .NET Core 3.1

I'm following this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/connection-strings/kusto

This is what I'm doing:

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(clusterUri);
var managedIdentity = "<managed identity>";

var kustoConnectionStringBuilder = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(clusterUri))
                                       .WithAadManagedIdentity(managedIdentity);
```

But I keep getting this error:

"**Exception Message: Tried the following 3 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.**"

What am I doing wrong?
Is there a simple way to connect to the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the exception text, you are not getting it from Kusto SDK.
Can you debug to see what line in your code is throwing this error?
If you are using managed identities and the identity you need is available in your environment, you do not need the first two lines; all you need is the managed identity id.

Alternatively, if you wish to perform the auth yourself, you need to follow the "token provider" pattern and use the AzureServiceTokenProvider's GetAccessTokenAsync method:

```
Func<string> tokenProviderCallback; // User-defined method to retrieve the access token

// Recommended syntax
var kustoConnectionStringBuilder = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(serviceUri)
    .WithAadTokenProviderAuthentication(tokenProviderCallback);
```

Comment: The line that it fails is: "Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider". Not sure what do you mean by "in your environment". Also, regarding your 2nd option - if I'm debugging in my VS, how would I get a token when running locally. I also see that it tries to authenticate in 3 ways and one of the ways is through "visual Studio Token provider file" called "tokenprovider.json". Is there something I need to do in

Comment: That means exactly what I was trying to say - you are failing to configure or use the token provider. Line "Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider" canot fail by itself - it's just a type name, so you will need to provide much more information that that.